# Four complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ lie on a generalized circle if and only if they have a real cross ratio $[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, circles, conformal-geometry

*Let $[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]$ denote the [cross ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) of the complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4\in \mathbb{C}$. Show that the distinct points $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4\in\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ lie on a generalized circle if and only if $[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]\in\mathbb{R}$.*

---

I saw this statement claimed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/142179/100167), and wondered how one would go about showing it. I know of some facts we could work with:

- First, the definition: A [generalized circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle) in $\mathbb{C}$ is either a circle or a line in $\mathbb{C}$.
- I know that a Mobius transformation maps generalized circles to generalized circles.
- I know that if $f$ is a Mobius transformation and $z_j'=f(z_j)$, $j=1,2,3,4$, then $[z_1',z_2',z_3',z_4']=[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]$.

I have posted a potential proof as an answer below. Please let me know if you think it's complete. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

We will show (1) if $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ lie on a generalized circle, then $[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]\in\mathbb R$, and (2) if $[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]\in\mathbb R$, then $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ lie on a generalized circle.

1. First, suppose $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ lie on a generalized circle. We know that, given three real numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a Mobius transformation
   \begin{equation*}
   F=F_{x_1,x_2,x_3}^{-1} \circ F_{z_1,z_2,z_3}
   \end{equation*}
   such that $F(z_i)=x_i$, $i=1,2,3$. Also, since Mobius transformations map generalized circles to generalized circles, we know that $z_4$ is also mapped to some $x_4 \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, since $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \in \mathbb{R}$, then their cross ratio $[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]=\frac{x_1-x_3}{x_2-x_3}\cdot\frac{x_2-x_4}{x_1-x_4} \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, since the cross ratio is invariant under Mobius transformation, we have
   \begin{align*}
    [z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]
    &=[F(z_1),F(z_2),F(z_3),F(z_4)] \\
    &=[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] \\
    &=\frac{x_1-x_3}{x_2-x_3}\cdot\frac{x_2-x_4}{x_1-x_4} \\
    &\in \mathbb{R}
    \end{align*}
2. Next, suppose $[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4] \in \mathbb{R}$. Let
   \begin{equation*}
   F=F_{x_1,x_2,x_3}^{-1} \circ F_{z_1,z_2,z_3}
   \end{equation*}
   be the Mobius transformation which sends $F(z_i)=x_i$, $i=1,2,3$, and let $z_4'=F(z_4)$. Since the cross ratio is invariant under Mobius transformation, we know that 
   \begin{equation*}
   [z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]=[x_1,x_2,x_3,z_4']
   \end{equation*}
   Therefore the cross ratio $[x_1,x_2,x_3,z_4']$ is also a real number, which implies that $z_4'$ is a real number as well. Now consider $F^{-1}$, which is also a Mobius transformation. Since $x_1,x_2,x_3,z_4'$ lie on a generalized circle (the real line), and since a Mobius transformation maps generalized circles to generalized circles, then $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4 \in F^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ belong to a generalized circle.

Comment: Very good answer. You have done great work.which text book you follow for complex analysis??

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$
**Lemma:** If $|z|=|w|$, then
$$
\arg(z-w)=\frac{\arg(z)+\arg(w)}2\pm\frac\pi2\tag1
$$
**Proof:** Let $z=re^{ia}$ and $w=re^{ib}$.
$$
\begin{align}
re^{ia}-re^{ib}
&=\color{#C00}{2}r\,\frac{e^{i(a-b)/2}-e^{i(b-a)/2}}{\color{#C00}{2}\color{#090}{i}}\,\color{#090}{e^{i\pi/2}}e^{i(a+b)/2}\tag{2a}\\
&=2r\sin\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)\,e^{i(a+b+\pi)/2}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\sin\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)$ might be positive or negative, the argument might be $\frac{a+b+\pi}2$ or $\frac{a+b-\pi}2$.

$\large\square$

---

**Invariance of the Cross Ratio**

A cross ratio is unchanged by the translation (represented by $b$), rotation (represented by $\arg(a)$), and scaling (represented by $|a|$) in the map $z\mapsto az+b$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{((az_1+b)-(az_3+b))\ ((az_2+b)-(az_4+b))}{((az_2+b)-(az_3+b))\
\ ((az_1+b)-(az_4+b))}
&=\frac{a(z_1-z_3)\ a(z_2-z_4)}{a(z_2-z_3)\ a(z_1-z_4)}\tag{3a}\\
&=\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_2-z_3)(z_1-z_4)}\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Moving Three Points to the Real Line or the Unit Circle**

For three collinear points, translate one of the points to the origin and rotate the others to the real axis.

For three non-collinear points, translate their circumcenter to the origin, then scale so the points are all on the unit circle.

---

**Mapping a Fourth Point**

Define
$$
\begin{align}
f(\color{#C00}{z})
&=\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-\color{#C00}{z})}{(z_2-z_3)(z_1-\color{#C00}{z})}\tag{4a}\\
&=\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}\left(\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_1-\color{#C00}{z}}+1\right)\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
Then, as long as $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are not coincident, $f$ is bijective on the Riemann Sphere ($\mathbb{C}^\ast$). In fact,
$$
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(\color{#C00}{w})
&=\frac{\color{#C00}{w}\,z_1(z_2-z_3)-z_2(z_1-z_3)}{\color{#C00}{w}\,(z_2-z_3)-(z_1-z_3)}\tag{5a}\\
&=z_1\frac{\color{#C00}{w}-\frac{z_2}{z_1}\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}}{\color{#C00}{w}-\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}}\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
As mentioned above, any three points can be moved either to the real line or to the unit circle using a map $z\mapsto az+b$. Furthermore, the map $z\mapsto az+b$ preserves the cross ratio.

Therefore, all that needs to be considered is either $\Im(z_1)=\Im(z_2)=\Im(z_3)=0$ (three points on the real axis) or $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$ (three points on the unit circle).

**Case $\boldsymbol{1}$: $\boldsymbol{\Im(z_1)=\Im(z_2)=\Im(z_3)=0}$**

Since $z_1,z_2,z_3\in\mathbb{R}$, $f:\mathbb{R}^\ast\to\mathbb{R}^\ast$ and $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^\ast\to\mathbb{R}^\ast$ (where $\mathbb{R}^\ast=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$).

Thus, if three of four points are collinear, then the cross-ratio of the four points is real iff all four points are collinear.

**Case $\boldsymbol{2}$: $\boldsymbol{|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1}$**

Let's first prove a Corollary of the Lemma.

**Corollary:** Suppose $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$. Then
$$
\frac{z_2}{z_1}\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}=\overline{\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}}\tag6
$$
**Proof:**
$$
\begin{align}
\arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}\right)
&=\left(\frac{\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_3)}2\pm\frac\pi2\right)-\left(\frac{\arg(z_2)+\arg(z_3)}2\pm\frac\pi2\right)\tag{7a}\\
&\equiv\frac{\arg(z_1)-\arg(z_2)}2\pmod{\pi}\tag{7b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(7a):}$ apply the Lemma
$\text{(7b):}$ $\pm\frac\pi2-\pm\frac\pi2\equiv0\pmod{\pi}$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\arg\left(\frac{z_2}{z_1}\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}\right)+\arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}\right)
&=\arg\left(\frac{z_2}{z_1}\right)+2\arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}\right)\tag{8a}\\[3pt]
&\equiv\arg(z_2)-\arg(z_1)\\[3pt]
&+2\left(\frac{\arg(z_1)-\arg(z_2)}2\pmod{\pi}\right)\tag{8b}\\[3pt]
&\equiv0\pmod{2\pi}\tag{8c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(8a):}$ multiplication is associative
$\text{(8b):}$ $\arg\left(\frac{z_2}{z_1}\right)=\arg(z_2)-\arg(z_1)$
$\phantom{\text{(8b):}}$ apply $(7)$
$\text{(8c):}$ $2(x\pmod{\pi})=2x\pmod{2\pi}$

Since $|z_1|=|z_2|$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{z_2}{z_1}\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}\right|=\left|\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}\right|\tag9
$$
$(8)$ and $(9)$ show that $\frac{z_2}{z_1}\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}$ and $\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}$ have the same absolute value and opposite arguments. Thus, they are conjugates.

$\large\square$

Suppose $|z|=1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\arg(f(z))
&=\arg\left(\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z)}{(z_2-z_3)(z_1-z)}\right)\tag{10a}\\
&=\left(\frac{\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_3)}2\pm\frac\pi2+\frac{\arg(z_2)+\arg(z)}2\pm\frac\pi2\right)\\
&-{}\left(\frac{\arg(z_2)+\arg(z_3)}2\pm\frac\pi2+\frac{\arg(z_1)+\arg(z)}2\pm\frac\pi2\right)\tag{10b}\\[3pt]
&\equiv0\pmod\pi\tag{10c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(10a):}$ definition of $f$
$\text{(10b):}$ apply the Lemma
$\text{(10c):}$ $\pm\frac\pi2+\pm\frac\pi2\equiv0\pmod{\pi}$

That is, the cross-ratio of $4$ concyclic points is real.

Suppose that $w\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\left|f^{-1}(w)\right|
&=\left|\,z_1\frac{w-\frac{z_2}{z_1}\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}}{w-\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}}\,\right|\tag{11a}\\
&=\left|\,\frac{\overline{w}-\overline{\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}}}{w-\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}}\,\right|\tag{11b}\\[9pt]
&=1\tag{11c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(11a):}$ apply $\text{(5b)}$
$\text{(11b):}$ $|z_1|=1$ and $\overline{w}=w$ since $w\in\mathbb{R}$
$\phantom{\text{(11b):}}$ apply the Corollary
$\text{(11c):}$ $\left|\overline{z}\right|=|z|$

That is, if the cross-ratio of $4$ non-collinear points is real, they are concyclic.

Answer (score 0):

First, show that every generalized circle can be sent by a Mobius transformation to the real line (transitivity). 
Then, all you have to do is to show that if the cross ratio of $4$ real points is always real.

Also note that this theorem can be shown with elementary geometry using the inscribed angle theorem.

Comment: OK, naturally if $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\frac{x_1-x_3}{x_2-x_3}\cdot\frac{x_2-x_4}{x_1-x_4} \in \mathbb{R}$. But can you elaborate on the part about every generalized circle can be mapped by a Mobius transformation to the real line please?

Comment: Here are precisions about the first point. If you have $\mathcal{C}$ a generalized circle, you have to find a Mobius transformation such that $f(\mathcal{C})  = \mathbb{R}$. This is not trivial and be done in different ways.

Comment: Extra hint : take $3$ distincts points among the $4$ you have. Is there a Mobius transformation sending the first to 0, the second to $\infty$ and the third to $1$ ? If yes, where is the image if the last point ?

Answer (score 0):

Define $T(z)= [z,z_2,z_3,z_4]$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Case $1$: $z_i$'s lie on a straight line.

In this case, $\arg(z_i-z_1)= \arg(z_2-z_1) \, \forall i\in \{2,3,4\}.$ It follows that $\arg T(z_1)=2\pi k\implies T(z_1)\in \mathbb R$.

Case $2$: $z_i$'s lie on a circle.

In this case, calculations show that $T(z_1)= \overline{T(z_1)}\implies T(z_1)\in \mathbb R.$

For the other direction, the following theorem would make things straightforward.

**Theorem** A Mobius transformation maps straight lines and circles *onto* straight lines and circles.

**Remarks:**

$(1)$ The theorem doesn't say that a straight line necessary goes to a straight line, similarly for a circle.

$(2)$ Consider the map $f: \mathbb C_\infty\to \mathbb C_\infty:z\mapsto 1/z$.  Consider the equation of a generalised circle $a(x^2+y^2)+bx+cy+d=0.$ Writing $z=x+\iota y, f(z)= u+\iota v= \frac{1}{x+\iota y}\implies x=\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}, y=\frac{v}{u^2+v^2}$.  Setting these in the equation of the circle: $d(u^2+v^2)+bu+cv+a=0$, which is a generalised circle. So $f$ maps generalised circles to generalise circles.

**Pf. of the theorem:** A Mobius transformation is a composition of *translation, dilation and f*. Translation and dilation map generalised circles to generalised circles and $f$ does the same too by Remark $(2)$. Thus, the statement of the theorem follows.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that $T(z_1)\in \mathbb R$. Clearly, $T(z_2)=1, T(z_3)=0$. Consider the Mobius transformation $S:= T^{-1}$. By the Theorem above, $S$ maps the $x-$ axis onto a generalised circle. It follows that $S(T(z_1)), S(T(z_2)), S(T(z_3)), S(T(z_4))$, which are $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ respectively, lie on a generalised circle.